# Use Passport authenticate without successRedirect option

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware, passport-local

I'm using the local strategy with the following configuration:

```
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: `Unknown user ${username}` });
        }
        if (user.password !== password) {
          return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    });
  })
);
```

And the `login` end point is defined below like this:

```
server.post(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
  })
);
```

This works successfully as expected, however I don't need to use the `successRedirect` option, but if I remove this option I get a `404` status code response when doing the request:

> POST http://localhost:3001/login 404 (Not Found)

Here is the code without `successRedirect`:

```
server.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"));
```

I've also tried to set up `authenticate` with other options but without `successRedirect`, however I get the same error message.

The dependency versions I'm using are: `express 4.16.4`, `passport 0.4.0` and `passport-local 1.0.0`

Comment: You can add other middleware after the passport with the response and remove the authenticate redirect sucess.  In the [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) you can see an example of this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Here is the syntax I've used in my case:

`server.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(201);
});`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
  if (err) {
    res.redirect("/login");
  } else {
    if (!user) {
      res.redirect("/login");
    } else {
      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          res.redirect("/login");
        } else {
          res.redirect("/success");
        }
      });
    }
  }
})(req, res);
```